# assert() function not showing up in disassembly

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

My coworker just asked me to help on a problem, he has a few lines in his code as

```
for (long counter = 0; counter < End; )
{
  ...
  assert(counter++ < MAX);
  ...
}
```

The problem is, when we use Visual Studio to debug line by line, seems the assert() line got skipped all the time, and `counter` never got incremented and thus the loop never finished.

When we look at the disassembly using VS, there is no assembly line for this assert() function. I never used assert() before, so I'm wondering is this normal and he shouldn't put any code behavior into assert() or something is wrong here with debugger or other?

Thanks.

Comment: `assert` is a macro that can be defined to `(void)0`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: You are putting side effects (`counter++`) in an `assert()` call, which is implemented as a macro 99.9% of the time and, in that case, doesn't even *evaluate* its argument in release mode. You should perform your side effects first, then call `assert()` on the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that `NDEBUG` is *not* defined, as `assert` is enabled only in debug build, i.e when `NDEBUG` is not defined.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert):

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(condition) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(condition) /*implementation defined*/
#endif
```

That is, when `NDEBUG` is defined, `assert` is no-op which is what you observe in assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest answer.

Answer (score 4):

**You should only use assert for debugging purposes.**

The line

```
assert(counter++ < MAX);
```

contains logic, and it shouldn't.

In a non-debug build, it will never be executed.

Answer (score 3):

`assert` is a macro, which is removed in release builds. So unless you're looking at a debug build, don't expect to see any `assert` code.

And because `assert` is a macro, and not a function, it's not likely to look like a single function call either.

Answer (score 1):

Asserts typically get removed from release builds and therefore are executed only for debug builds. You should never have any side effects affecting program logic in assert.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is built under Release Mode, the assert statements will not be included. Is your coworker using Release Mode?

Visual Studio's optimization settings may also remove the assert statements.

Couldn't your coworker change the for loop to not use the assert statement?